# Smalltalk throwing nextLine Error

Tags: smalltalk, visualworks

For Smalltalk do we need to import some library to use nextLine?

```
Transcript show: 'Whatz your name?'. 
userName := stdin nextLine.
```

When I try to evaluate it throws an error.

Comment: What error does it throw? What is stdin?

Comment: Would it be much trouble for you to provide exactly what error you are seeing?

Comment: ex return:
       (#errSelectorNotPrintable << #dialogs >> '** unprintable selector **')
       expandMacros asString].
   (#errNotUnderstood << #dialogs >> 'Message not understood: <1s>')
    expandMacrosWith: selectorString];

Comment: That's an example return? What error do you get with the code you are showing in your question? And as has been asked already: where and how is `stdin` defined? You might want to [watch this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mKSKuc6D8x8).

Comment: Ohh ok... I didn't define stdin. I assumed that it is already defined.

Comment: you don't need to define stdin, the system defines it already. It's a global variable and as such its name starts with a capital S.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method #nextLine is implemented in Stream. Stdin should be a stream. But "stdin" (with lowercase) is probably a typo.

Comment: I am trying to take input from the user. So I  was looking and got that code for taking input.